# Draw listbox item properly vb.net 2005

Tags: .net, winforms, graphics, listbox, draw

i already can draw a listbox item rectangle in the listbox Drawitem event properly like this

[image]

```
'// Draw border ACA899
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width,e.Bounds.Height)
```

how do i

1. position theitem text in left-middle alignment?
2. correct the end of the x2,y2 (see picture) of the rectangle that is not showing to show properly?
3. specify the thickness of the drawn rectangle?

thanks

Comment: The documentation for DrawString and DrawRectangle are pretty clear on alignment, thickness, and bounds - along with examples.  Did you check those?

Comment: i am using the express edition of visual studio, and don't have any documentation, where is the online version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself, thanks to those who helped

```
'// Draw border ACA899
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width-1,e.Bounds.Height)
```